# not able to Trigger dll located at another machine from my server

Tags: jenkins, vstest

On my Jenkin server, i mapped a driver of my test machine project folder (where my unit test.dll exists).

Now i wanted to trigger from server >>vstest.console.exe Z:\unit test.dll

it throws warning as below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You said that you mapped a drive, but the output shows UNC path (\\server\...), which is unsupported in many tools. If you map a drive, you should also make sure the user running the Jenkins see this drive. I suggest adding a "net use" command as part of your build to make sure the job uses the mapped drive.

Comment: I added net use command and see the drive. but why can not i trigger the dll from mapped drive using vstest.console.exe from server  e.g. From Server >>vstest.console.exe Z:\SeleniumUnitTest.dll /UseVsixExtensions:True

Comment: What errors do you get now?

Comment: I have added 2nd picture to original question. Even i tried /platform:x64 /inisolation. I just wanted to trigger this (local machine)dll from vstest.console.exe remotely(at server)

Comment: I'm not familiar with these errors. Look them up online. Maybe a 32/64 bit issue? Does it work for you if you run it from command line?

Comment: yes on same machine, i could trigger it using VSTEST.CONSOLE.EXE but while trying to access remotely i could not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81841/discussion-between-sudhir-pradhan-and-eldad-ak).

Comment: I think you mean to run the tests on the test server. If this is the case, you should do it with a Jenkins slave. Look it up.